# How to get image within a slider to overlay proceeding div?

Tags: html, css, slider, z-index, positioning

I cannot get the images on the right of the slider to overlay the following div underneath it. I've used a variety of different position and z-index variables and cannot get it to work.

[Live Site](http://suncoastdiesel-com.3dcartstores.com/)

What I'm using for slider images:

```
.overlay-img{
position:absolute;
right:0;
z-index:9999;
top:-300px;}
```

What I'm using for the following div (underneath):

```
.lower-stack{
position:relative;
z-index:1;}
```

[Effect I'm trying to achieve (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtbYz.png). Any help appreciated. What am I missing?

Comment: Be sure to include any relevant code in your comment in your question, as described at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Updated with image and code. Thanks.

Comment: And where's the `div.lower-stack`? I can't find it on your live site.

Comment: I'm still not entirely seeing what you're trying to accomplish to be entirely honest. I can't see what you're trying to make visible that isn't already.

Comment: @AvAvt the div.lower-stack is where it says "SunCoast Diesel" (see image) the black div beneath the slider.

Comment: @jdsfighter http://i.stack.imgur.com/KtbYz.png is what Im trying to get at, with the right image coming down over the div beneath it (black div).

Comment: @AvAvt Is there any other information I can provide that might help?

Comment: I got it, working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swipper's outer most wrapper was having `overflow: hidden`, which prevent child content from being visible outside its boundaries.

```
.swiper-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You can consider adding an id to that particular container, and make it `overflow: visible`:

```
#newID{
    overflow: visible;
}
```

When you do that, slides start showing to the right side of the page and a horizontal scroll bar appear. To fix that, add `overflow: hidden` to `.mainContent`:

```
.mainContent{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Don't set `z-index: 9999` to the image, it is not needed.

Comment: This worked. I had to change the .swiper-container to have a higher index and it worked. Thank you!